# Vhosts not redirecting

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, vhosts

I have a server running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I am trying to set up vhosts. What I did already is,
1) Created 2 files desktopia.be.conf and everybodycreative.be.conf which look like this

desktopia.be.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin your_email_address
        ServerName desktopia.be
        ServerAlias www.desktopia.be

        DocumentRoot /var/www/desktopia
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/desktopia>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

everybodycreative.be.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin your_email_address
    ServerName everybodycreative.be
    ServerAlias www.everybodycreative.be

    DocumentRoot /var/www/everybodycreative
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/everybodycreative>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Under the www folder, I made 2 folders named desktopia and everybodycreative.

After I did that, I ran the following commands

```
sudo a2ensite desktopia.be
sudo a2ensite everybodycreative.be
```

and restarted the apache2 service.

Now the problem is that when I connect on one of the 2 domain names, I just get to see the content of my www folder as you can see here http://desktopia.be/

If anyone can tell me where I should look or what more information is needed to fix this problem, please ask me so that I can fix this. This has been bothering me for a few days already and I need this fixed asap.

Thanks for helping me already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to run

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

to turn on rewrite module.

Then in the relative folder .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.desktopia\.be
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.desktopia\.be [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /var/www/desktopia/%1/$1
```

same for other url,

I haven't tried it so you may need to modify something in the .htaccess folder code

Comment: But it's on a server I am remote connecting

Comment: I changed the code, now it might work for your server

Comment: I did the a2enmod rewrite restarted apache2 service and it worked, I did not even had to use the code you posted. Tho can you explain top me what it does pleas?

Comment: a2enmod rewrite enables module rewrite,

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the NameVirtualHosts directive in your config.